# Search Json fetch Result data using Kotlin

Tags: android, json, android-studio, kotlin, search

I am fetching JSON from [URL](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/unity-b69ff.appspot.com/o/new.json?alt=media&token=dc24acb2-13aa-40da-b0c5-7bb3ccd59af8) using OKhttp...
**I am Using Kotlin.**

```
{
"CountryName": [{
        "Country": "India",
        "CountryCode": "+91",
        "Population": "545121546846"
    },
    {
        "country ": "Pakistan",
        "countryCode": "+92",
        "Population": "23546546546"
    },

    {
        "Country": "UK",
        "CountryCode": "+42",
        "Population": "545121546846"
    },
    {
        "Country": "US",
        "CountryCode": "+1",
        "Population": "54512154545846"
    }


]
```

}

When successfully fetched data its show only when user search **Country** and add to a list and show its related data like countryside and population. I am able to fetch JSON data, **But unable to control it like when user search and add to List.** This is my main Activity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

             fetchjson()
     }
```

//This is How I fetch JSON

```
fun fetchjson() {

    val url = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/unity-b69ff.appspot.com/o/new.json?alt=media&token=dc24acb2-13aa-40da-b0c5-7bb3ccd59af8"

    val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()
    val client = OkHttpClient()
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(object: Callback {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {

            println("Fail to load json")
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {

            val body = response.body?.string()
            println(body)

            val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
          val homefeed = gson.fromJson(body, HomeFeed::class.java)

            runOnUiThread{
                recyclerView.adapter = MainAdapter(homefeed)

            }

        }
    })

}
      }
```

This Is my MainAdapter

```
 class adapter(val homefeed: jjson) : RecyclerView.Adapter 
   <adapter.CustomViewHolder>(), Filterable {

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return homefeed.CountryName.count()
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomViewHolder {
    val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    val cellforRow = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false)
    return CustomViewHolder(cellforRow)

}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val v = homefeed.CountryName.get(position)
    holder.itemView.textView2.text = v.Country
    holder.itemView.textView.text = v.CountryCode.toString()

}

class CustomViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {}

                         // this filter method 
override fun getFilter(): Filter {
   return (object: Filter(){
       override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence?): FilterResults {
          // TODO("Not yet implemented")
       }

       override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence?, results: FilterResults?) {
          // TODO("Not yet implemented")
       }
   })
}


  }
                  //json data object

       class jjson(val CountryName: List<name>)
       class name{
           val Country: String? = null
           val CountryCode: Int? = null
           val Popuplation: Long? = null
                                          }
```

**CAN I EXECUTE SOME CODE WRITTEN IN JSON WHILE AFTER FETCHING**

Comment: Your issue is not clear, can you elaborate a little more your final question?

Comment: Code which i mentioned above is just fetch all json data in recyclers view.  But, I want, implent search view in app and initialy list would be empty untill users search and add item...

Comment: Simply, i want show certain data instead of all data in view. And the data is searched by the only country name only if the user search anything except country name its show error .And when user search with country name its also show all data related to that country name. Like, Country Code and population..

Comment: So, you don't want to display the whole list of countries after a user search? You should filter the country list by the user query and update the adapter with that filtered data.

Comment: @JuanMartinez exactly, i was unable explain problem. But, This I want. And also, initialy list would be empty

Answer (score 1):

Now that I understand a little better your problem, I'm writing an answer.

Remember that your adapter only takes care of displaying a set of data, in this case the list of countries you want the user to see. Currently, you're just initializing the adapter with the whole list of countries once you receive the response from the server.
That you could do is initialize the adapter with an empty list, update the adapter dataset when the countries are fetched from the server and then update it again everytime the user search query changes.
You may need to use a different type of adapter (an ArrayAdapter for example), to make it easier to work with your list data. You can read more about it here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout#AdapterViews

Once you have your adapter set up, what you need to do is:
1. Initialize it with an empty list, it can be done on its constructor.
2. Update its dataset when the countries come from the server:

```
adapter.clear()
adapter.addAll(countries)
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

3. Update its dataset when the user makes a search:

```
adapter.clear()
adapter.addAll(yourFilteredCountries) // you can keep the whole list of countries in a variable in the activity and just pass a filtered list here
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Note that this is a super simple approach and you can improve it in many ways, but it will help you understand how adapters work.

Let me know how it goes

Comment: where should I plug this code, in main Activity or In Adapter

Comment: You should add it in your Activity

Comment: **.clear()**, **.addAll()**, **.notifyDataSetChanged()** is always show error in android studio. even after import. Maybe, I plug this code in the wrong way. Please see my above source code and tell me the right place. please help me to implement the filter method.